# Ubuntu crash: This problem report applies to a program which is not installed any more

Tags: 16.04, crash, error-handling, teamviewer

I have had some error with team viewer in the past and as I do not use it, I have removed it.
I am wondering why do I see this problem with such an error message:

> This problem report applies to a program which is not installed any more.

The reported executable file also does not exist.

Where is the root of this problem? Who does call such an application?

[image: ubuntu internal error]

Comment: How did you remove it? Maybe it left some service or something which is causing this error?

Comment: Using a terminal enter systemctl status. This should give you a list of active services. If you look down the list you will probably find something related to teamviewer, quite possibly teamviewerd. Then it’s a case of disabling that service. systemctl stop service-name and systemctl disable service-name

Comment: @PonJar, Thanks, I ran `systemctl` and the result is [here](https://pastebin.com/2848wuGh). It is too big to be pasted here.

Comment: The command “systemctl status” is much easier to read. Did you find anything relating to teamviewer  in the output you posted? I’m not in a position to search it myself currently

Comment: I've searched your output and there is nothing there to suggest teamviewer still has a service running. This article has some teamviewer terminal commands that are like the systemctl commands to manage services. https://www.ubuntupit.com/how-to-install-and-configure-teamviewer-on-ubuntu-linux/ I suggest you try "teamviewer daemon status" and see if anything useful is returned. If there is a daemon running then "teamviewer daemon disable" might solve your problem, but that's just a guess